Is the remote cache uploaded during the build process?
When multiple targets of a project are built together, does it upload the remote cache during the build process, or wait until all builds are completed before uploading?
Analyzing the logs, I didn't see whether it was uploaded during or after the build.

Uploading happens directly during building. Once an artifact is built it is uploaded.
